Comparing two lists to each other in Ansible
I am making my own small cluster server and configuring everything through Ansible but I am a bit stuck on checking whether or not a variable has been inserted into /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt or not.
Assume group_vars/all.yml contains the following definition:
cgroup_vars:
  - 'cgroup_enable=cpuset'
  - 'cgroup_memory=1'
  - 'cgroup_enable=memory'

I load the content into a variable with the following tasks in my playbook:
  - name: Read cmdline.txt for use below.
    shell: 'cat /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt'
    register: cmdline

  - name: Get individual environmental variables from cmdline.txt
    set_fact:
      cmd_vars: "{{ cmdline.stdout | split() }}"

Output of {{ cmd_vars | to_nice_yaml }} would be something like:
  msg: |-
    - console=serial0,115200
    - console=tty1
    - root=PARTUUID=52e8c2a3-02
    - rootfstype=ext4
    - fsck.repair=yes
    - rootwait
    - cgroup_enable=cpuset
    - cgroup_memory=1
    - cgroup_enable=memory

This should leave me with two lists: cgroup_vars and cmd_vars.
How do I check that all items in cgroup_vars is found in cmd_vars?
I would prefer that the result is a new list that contains the answer if the individual item was found or not.

Hmm... Shortly after my question and a bit more searching on Google I found a solution that does the job a bit more simple than what I was planning.
The idea was that if any of the variables were missing, then I would just add the missing one and skip the rest.
This gave me the following playbook:

  # Copied from initial question
  - name: Read cmdline.txt for use below.
    shell: 'cat /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt'
    register: cmdline

  # Copied from initial question
  - name: Get individual environmental variables from cmdline.txt
    set_fact:
      cmd_vars: "{{ cmdline.stdout | split() }}"

  - name: Enable K3S cluster variables
    replace:
      path: '/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt'
      regexp: '^([\w](?!.*\b{{ item }}\b).*)$'
      replace: '\1 {{ item }}'
    loop: "{{ cgroup_vars }}"
    when: item not in cmd_vars

The replace section of the task is from Vladimir Botka's answer to a related question here.
I wanted to improve on his example, since his task does not take into account if variable has already been set, which means the same variables can be set over and over again on all nodes, if I add additional nodes to my cluster server and run my playbook again.
My first change to his answer was instead of defining the cgroup variable as items in the task, they were moved group_vars/all.yml instead and saved in the variable cgroup_vars.
I am looping through the items in cgroup_vars where the task will only be used if current item in the loop does not exist in cmd_vars.

Meanwhile, I added the solution.
